# Refresh fragment from tab layout on click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have a tab layout with 2 fragment and I have a toolbar with different options that belong to the activity which hosts the view pager.

When I click on a toolbar option, it clean the data from DB that are used in the fragment and then it should refresh it to apply changes at screen.

But I can't find a way to refresh the fragment from the activity.

Here is the fragment adapter :

```
 public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter


{

    private final List<Fragment>  lstFragment = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> lstTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return lstFragment.get(i);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return lstTitles.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return  lstTitles.size();
    }


    public void AddFragment (Fragment fragment , String title)
    {
        lstFragment.add(fragment);
        lstTitles.add(title);
    }

}
```

Here is the way I call it in the fragments in main :

```
      FragAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    ((FragmentAdapter) FragAdapter).AddFragment(new FragmentProgramme(),"Programmes");
    ((FragmentAdapter) FragAdapter).AddFragment(new FragmentPlanning(),"Agenda"); //FRAGMENT I WANT TO REFRESH

    mviewpager.setAdapter(FragAdapter);
    mtablayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
    mtablayout.setupWithViewPager(mviewpager);
```

In the main, I have the option on the toolbar and I would like to do something like this  :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int pos = item.getItemId();
        switch (pos)
        {       
                DatabaseAgenda.getInstance(this).dropDB(); //CLEAN DB
                // I would like to find a function like this : ((FragmentAdapter) FragAdapter).refresh(FragmentPlanning, "Agenda");

                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

The point is to simply destroy the fragment because all the data must be cleaned from screen and then recreate it so the users can add new data to it

I hope this is clear, thank you for your hlelp

I have found a lot answers but never what I was really looking for

Comment: call notifydatasetchanged or set the adapter again for  viewpager  after dropping data from db.

Comment: It is working I did that : 
DatabaseAgenda.getInstance(this).dropDB();
                mviewpager.setAdapter(FragAdapter);
                mtablayout.setupWithViewPager(mviewpager);
                mtablayout.getTabAt(1).select();
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method setUserVisibleHint inside fragments to detect when it is visible. Data can be refreshed inside this method. Selecting the items of pageradapter programatically triggers setUserVisibleHint of present fragment. You would not need destroying fragments each time.

Comment: I created setUserVisibleHint  in the fragment method and called the refresh method but how do I select the item ?

Comment: I mean if I am already in the fragment when I want to clean data, it will not call setUserVisibleHint

Comment: There is another way, but a bit dirty. You have to keep a reference of both fragments inside parent activity/fragment. Then call public methods in fragment that has refresh data code.